# Qt C++ Вывод MessageBox или другого виджета при длительной загрузке

Tags: c++, qt, виджет, messagebox

Есть `QList` data; в него считываются `id` строк, данные из локальной БД. Далее эти строки загружаются в `tableWidget`. У каждого `id` может быть любое количество строк, а с годами данные буду накапливаться. Так вот, если

```
if (data.size > 1000) { 
//    создавался какой-нибудь виджет или вызывался метод
    show();
},
```

а при завершении цикла (как данные загрузились) он скрывался/удалялся автоматически.

Пробовал делать `QMessageBox` перед циклом. Сам `QMessageBox` был с сообщением и методом `show`, он показывался, но он был внутри пустой, без сообщения. И так как `tableWidget` заполнялся в цикле, сам виджет был подвисшим секунд 10.

Так вот я хочу, чтобы пока виджет был подвисшим, и в `tableWidget` грузились записи, отображался виджет типа `QMessageBox` c сообщением, а при завершении загрузки - исчезало/удалялось.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: для показа бокса лучше использовать подобные конструкции QMessageBox::critica()//эта выводит ошибки есть еще информационная и предупреждение. а рпо вашу задачу возможно имеет сымсл вынести вывод бокса в отдельный поток, который будет убиваться после завершения загрузки.

Comment: можно и так, но возможно кто то знает другой способ.

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите в сторону [QProgressDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант:

- перед загрузкой создать объект таймера, который сработает, например, через секунду
- повесить на срабатывание таймера вывод окошка или того, что нужно
- по окончании загрузки остановить таймер и отсоединить слот, в котором вызывается окошко

Так мы получим вывод окошка, если процесс работает больше, например, секунды. И ничего не произойдёт, если менее чем через секунду таймер будет удалён.

Comment: Примерно так и сделал уже, но всё равно спасибо. Пока не буду ставить галочку, может кто еще захочет внести свои 5 копеек в тему.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте после создания QMessageBox добавить QApplication::processEvents();, чтобы он успел обработаться